# This Duplicate is Not At All a Duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[How do I call a specific web service method with AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527345/how-do-i-call-a-specific-web-service-method-with-ajax)

In their wording these questions seem similar but outside of the word "jQuery" the two questions are completely different, as are the answers.  The "original" post is asking how to link to a jQuery library while the "duplicate" is asking how to use jQuery to make a SOAP API call.  Seems it would have made more sense for the moderators to re-word the original question and label that one a duplicate to this one, say:

[Where do you include the jQuery library from? Google JSAPI? CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547384/where-do-you-include-the-jquery-library-from-google-jsapi-cdn)

And then un-mark the second one as duplicate and leave as is.

Comment: I'm okay with this question as it's something that comes up often enough in close-as-dupe scenarios.  With a dupe-hammer myself in Java, a point of contention comes up as, "the answer is different, so it's not exactly a dupe".  I'd love to see more answers contributed to this, in addition to the excellent answer already provided by iCodez.

Comment: I don't see that they are duplicate questions anyway. One of them is "why doesn't my code work" and looks like they didn't reference JQuery. The other is "how do I do..."

Comment: Yes, that's my point.  Similar wording but different questions.

Comment: Holy cow.  Thanks for staying with me on that one iCodez!

Comment: @DaveKaye - I deleted my answer because it is no longer relevant to your edited question.  What would you like me to do?  Keep an off-topic answer?  I cannot address your new question because, as I said, I do not know enough about JQuery and AJAX to make informed decisions.

Comment: No no, I was being serious, no sarcasm.  I also see the duplicate status was removed.  THANK YOU!  Have a great weekend.

Comment: Oh, you too! Sorry for jumping the gun, but you know how internet chatting is what with no visible emotions. :)

Answer (score 1):

With iCodez' help I clarified my explanation of why the question was not a duplicate and the duplicate marking has been changed.  Thanks to all who provided input.